# Verify repository's key

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

According to wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Debian to install ROS on Debian, the GnuPG-key used to sign the repository should be installed by using

wget packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -

However, the key stored in ros.key hasn't been signed by anyone and the server doesn't support HTTPS.  So this key doesn't provide much security against person-in-the-middle-attacks. Would it be possible to have this key signed by admins or developers actively using GnuPG/PGP (i.e. they already participated a key-signing-party or otherweise exchanged they public key with some people), who can assure, that this is the genuine archive's key? Is there any SSL-enabled webserver available which could be used to provide the key?

Kind regards,
B. Wildenhain

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174166/verify-repository%27s-key/) by [bwildenhain](https://answers.ros.org/users/18928/bwildenhain/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2014-06-20

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-06-20**:
@William @tfoote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The key is now available on keyserver.ubuntu.com

The wget line can be replaced with

```
sudo -E apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
```

Please test that it works and then we can update the installation instructions.

Update:

It is also now available from the [ros/rosdistro repo](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/ros.key) on GitHub over https at: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key

Or of course you can get it via git over ssh.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bwildenhain](https://answers.ros.org/users/18928/bwildenhain/) on 2014-06-20**:
Thanks, looks good :-)

**Comment by [ajm](https://answers.ros.org/users/42179/ajm/) on 2019-07-08**:
There seems to be some kind of issue with the `apt-key adv...` command you provided on kinetic with Ubuntu 16.04, I had to manually download the key then do `sudo apt-key add ros.key`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-08**:
@ajm: I believe you're actually running into #q325039. The keys have changed since this answer was posted.

Edit: I've edited the answer by @tfoote and updated the command and the key.

**Comment by [bwildenhain](https://answers.ros.org/users/18928/bwildenhain/) on 2019-07-18**:
Thanks for the update. I can confirm that it now works in a more secure way. However, I would suggest the following two lines to adapt the code for Debian users, which are not using oldoldstable (current version is buster). The signed-by approch is suggested by https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty

1. sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros.org-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -s -c) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
2. wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -O - | gpg --dearmor | sudo dd of=/usr/share/keyrings/ros.org-keyring.gpg

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can get the key from the server, but it doesn't increase security: The HKP protocol used to communicate with keyserver is based on HTTP, not on HTTPS. Quote from https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-shaw-openpgp-hkp-00#section-8:
"all search results must be regarded as untrustworthy and informational only"

---

Originally posted by [bwildenhain](https://answers.ros.org/users/18928/bwildenhain/) with karma: 73 on 2014-06-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1